# ASP.NET C# DateTime Models/Controller/View Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a model Toto with a DateTime Time.
I have a basic controller who can edit Toto.
In the edit view, I can see the date in format : MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM(PM)
I store that Time in a database.
But how can I display it in this format: dd/MM/yyyy.

I already found a way, I just add

> [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=false, DataFormatString =
>   "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]

It works well when i look at all my entries but in the edit mode I have the same basic format (MM/dd...).
So I change :

> ApplyFormatInEditMode=true

The format in the edit view is good but when I save it, it tells me that : The value '30/10/2012' is not valid for Time.

How can I apply the format in the Edit view ?

Many thanks.

---

To be clear, I want the format : dd/MM/yyyy and not MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the DataFormatString to {0:d} as like

`[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]`

Comment: Ok, I don't have the hours but the format is still MM/dd/yyyy and i want it dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: @MaT Then it's `DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"`

Comment: Yes that's what i tried, but when I go in the Edit page and I enter a date in the format dd/MM/yyyy it gives me the error : The value '30/10/2012' is not valid for Time